# ASP.NET web api authentication with bacbone.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I'm implementing a RESTful web service using ASP.Net Web Api and Backbone.js at client side. What will the best way to authenticate user?

Comment: which authentication mode?

Comment: I want to build simple log/log out for individual user. I am done with hours of Googling but i m not able to find a simple solution.

Comment: would this web service work in intranet or internet?

Comment: internet Please help me out i am still not able to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You are building SPA then it is recommend to use Token Based Authentication not Cookies, once you obtain the access token from the Auth server (Web API) you need to store it in html5 local storage then with each subsequent request to a protected resource you need to send this access token in the "Authorization" header using bearer scheme.

I've compiled [detailed post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) about this but it uses Angular, so it will be very close to backbone.js